# formula1 formulalocal conditional formatting, language difference

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a problem with setting conditional formatting.

I am working in polish version of excel and if i write COUNTIF in english it won't work. It will work only if I will write COUNTIF in polish.
I tried with formulalocal but without success

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
Range("A5:C5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF($E5:$M5;""<0"")>0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5263615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: Create the conditional formatting manually, then use VBA to see what `activecell.FormatConditions(1).formula1` contains. It should give you a good hint.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez its countif in polish: =LICZ.JEŻELI($E5:$M5;"<0")>0

Comment: then use that !?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez but it wont work in english version of excel